# Using method from dll and WCF method interchangeably

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, inversion-of-control

I have dll which implements some business logic. I have created WCF service that exposes method which uses this dll. Finally there is also an application which calls WCF service. But in some cases it is better to call method from dll rather than calling WCF service method. And my question is "how to tell application which method must be used (from wcf or from dll)?".
Do I have to use IOC? Could you provide me an example how to do that?

Comment: Your question is too vague. In what cases is it better to call a method from the dll directly?  Why would you not use the dll in all cases?

Comment: When performance is very important then method should be called directly from dll. I can use calling method from dll in all cases, but I want to know if it is possible to implement app to use dll and wcf methods interchangeably.

Comment: *how to tell application which method must be used (from wcf or from dll)* -- only you can answer that.  IoC can help, but you still have to decide on the logic for which one gets called, and when.

Comment: Isn't performance always important? I'm sorry, but you are not making sense to me... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is about trust. If your application is trusted, it should call the DLL directly.

If your application is not trusted, for example it's a client app that can possibly make these calls when it shouldn't, then it should go through the WCF service so security can be controlled.

Until you can provide a compelling reason for your application to have a need to actually switch back and forth, it shouldn't.